# ON CONFLICT using pg_prepare() errors 'name' does not exist

Tags: php, postgresql, postgres-9.6

I have a simple DB class with this method

```
function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db) {
    $this->link = pg_connect("host=$host port=5432 dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass") or $this->error();
}

public function run($sql, $args = null) {
    if(!$args)
        $this->query = pg_query($sql);
    else {
        $v = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
        $this->query = pg_prepare($v, $sql);
        $this->query = pg_execute($v, $args);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Using this I can the following query without prepared statements, and it works perfectly fine.

```
$db->run("
    INSERT INTO userExercise (userid, exerciseid, date, sets)
    VALUES ($user->id, $exerciseid, '$date', '$sets')

    ON CONFLICT (userid, date, exerciseid)
    DO UPDATE SET sets = '$sets'

    RETURNING LASTVAL()"
);
```

However when I do a prepared, I get the error "ERROR:  prepared statement "41982c47c3c84749552cd9808ad03422" does not exist"

```
    $db->run("
        INSERT INTO userExercise (userid, exerciseid, date, sets)
        VALUES ($1, $2, $3 $4)

        ON CONFLICT (userid, date, exerciseid)
        DO UPDATE SET sets = $4

        RETURNING LASTVAL()",
        [$user->id, $exerciseid, $date, $sets]
    );
```

The `41982c47c3c84749552cd9808ad03422` resulting from `md5` to give a unique name. The issue appears to be from the `ON CONFLICT`. How I may fix this?

Comment: If you set `$v = "abc"`, does it work?

Comment: Same error. prepared statement "abc" does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are not checking the result from pg_prepare, and probably there is a syntax error. Like `VALUES ($1, $2, $3 $4)` should have 1 more comma.

Also, `RETURNING LASTVAL()` should probably be something like `RETURNING ID`, or whatever your serial column is called. Otherwise you will get bogus results for the conflict case.